Gunicorn Freeze issue
I'm encountering a problem with Gunicorn freezing. I'm hosting a Django application using Docker with Nginx as the web server container and Gunicorn as the application server. The Django instance is replicated in three instances with the following Gunicorn configuration.
# gunicorn_config.py

    worker_class = "gevent"

    bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"

    workers = 1
    worker_connections = 10

    max_requests = 1000
    max_requests_jitter = 50



    # Request timeout (adjust as needed)
    timeout = 200  # 30 seconds


    # Log settings
    accesslog = "-"  # Log to stdout
    errorlog = "-"   # Log to stderr
    loglevel="debug"

    # Preload the application before forking worker processes
    preload = True

gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py django_app.wsgi:application
Sometimes, my Gunicorn workers freeze and don't accept any incoming requests. In the Gunicorn log, the message shows the worker stops with signal 9 EPIPE. I can't seem to find the issue. It works fine after I restart the Django containers, same issue occurs after sometime. Meanwhile, I encountered an error on the Redis side: "BusyLoadingError: Redis is loading the dataset in memory." Redis is used for Celery broker, Django channels, and Django caching. Could Redis be the reason for the issue?
Package versions:
------------
django = "3.2.12"
celery = "5.1.2"
redis = "^4.4.1"
channels-redis = "^4.1.0"
django-cacheops = "^6.1"
django-redis = "^5.2.0"

